# He generado divs con javascript pero quise que con un click en ellos se eliminara pero tengo problemas al intentarlo

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function copic() {
    let color = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.colors')).backgroundColor;
    let colorText = document.querySelector('.hex').textContent;

    return color, colorText;
}
```

> Aqui he hecho que se me vuelva a generar los colores que ya he husado y que vayan a la galeria

```
const heart = document.getElementById("like");

function like() {
let guardar = copic()

let historia = document.createElement('div')
historia.style.background = guardar;
historia.className = "historia";

let textHistoria = document.createElement('p');
textHistoria.innerHTML = guardar;
textHistoria.className = "texthex";


let caja = document.createElement('div');
caja.id = 'caja-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
caja.append(historia);
caja.append(textHistoria);
caja.classList = 'caja';

const borrar = document.querySelector('.history');
borrar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let contenido = document.getElementById(caja.id);
    contenido.remove(remove);
```

> siempre me sale cannot 'remove is not defined' o 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')''
> Nose si e por aqui que tengo el problema, ayuda por favor

```
})

const elements = document.querySelector('.history')
elements.append(caja);
```

}

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Cuándo estás invocando esas funciones? El flujo del código es fundamental.

Comment: El `remove` que está como argumento no está definido en `contenido.remove(remove)`  supongo que quieres hacer algo como `contenido.remove(event.target);`